# Reference multiple cells with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.6, openpyxl

I'm trying to reference multiple cells in a function using openpyxl, like is shown in this code:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
import os

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()

ws.cell("A1").value = 1
ws.cell("A2").value = 2
ws.cell("A3").value = "=SUM(A1;A2)"

wb.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test.xlsx"))
```

When opening the output file with OpenOffice, the formula for cell A3 changes to `=SUM(A1|A2)` and the cell displays an error.

Why did the ";" character change and how can I solve this?

Comment: `SUM(A1;A2)` is not legal. Maybe you wanted `SUM(A1:A2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `SUM(A1;A2)` is not a valid Excel formula.

Now, with certain language settings (which use a comma as the decimal separator), a semicolon is used in place of a comma in formulae, but `openpyxl` explicitly [does not support this](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/usage.html#using-formulae) (emphasis mine):

> Warning
>
> NB you must use the English name for a function and **function arguments
>   must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as
>   semi-colons**.

So I imagine that it is replacing the illegal character (with something equally illegal). If you replace your `;` with a `:`, you should be OK

Comment: The ":" operator selects all the cells between two cells. Replacing the semicolon with a comma did what I wanted.